# Printing MySQL Query Results to JSP from Java Servlet

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, output

Right now I am facing the following two problems with this script.

1) When I run a command like `SELECT * FROM table;` it only returns the column names. When I run a command like `SELECT columnName FROM table;`, it displays the output perfectly. What could be causing this error?

2) When I run an `INSERT` or `DELETE` command, I get my feedback message saying the database was updated, but when checking the database, no changes have been made. Can anyone see what's wrong with that clause in my source code?

Below are my .java and .jsp files respectively:

databaseServlet.java

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class databaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private Connection conn;
    private Statement statement;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            Class.forName(config.getInitParameter("databaseDriver"));
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    config.getInitParameter("databaseName"),
                    config.getInitParameter("username"),
                    config.getInitParameter("password"));
            statement = conn.createStatement();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ArrayList<String[]> out = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();

        String query = request.getParameter("query");

        if (query.toString().toLowerCase().contains("select")) {
            //SELECT Queries
            try {
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query.toString());
                ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
                for(int i = 1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++){
                    columns.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
                }

                while (resultSet.next()){
                    String[] row = new String[numberOfColumns];
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++){
                        row[i] = (String) resultSet.getObject(i+1);
                    }
                    out.add(row);
                 }
            }
            catch (Exception f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (query.toString().toLowerCase().contains("delete") || query.toString().toLowerCase().contains("insert")) {
            //DELETE and INSERT commands
            try {
                conn.prepareStatement(query.toString()).executeUpdate(query.toString());
                columns.add("\t\t Database has been updated!");
            }
            catch (Exception l){
                l.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            //Not a valid response
            columns.add("\t\t Not a valid command or query!");
        }
        request.setAttribute("query", query);
        request.setAttribute("resultSize",  out.size());
        request.setAttribute("queryResults", out);
        request.setAttribute("queryColumns", columns);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/dbServlet.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,  response);
    }
}
```

dbServlet.jsp

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!-- dbServlet.html -->
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<head>
    <title>MySQL Servlet</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table{border: 1px solid #FFF;}
        td{border: 1px dashed #FFF; padding: 3px; background-color: #5A5F64;}
        body{background-color: #182229; text-align: center; color: #FFF;}
        h1{font-family:"Arial", sans-serif, Helvetica;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>MySQL Servlet User-Interface</h1>
    <div style="width:500px; margin-right:auto; margin-left: auto; background-color:#131B21; padding: 20px;">
        <h3>Enter an SQL Command!</h3>
        <form action = "/database/database" method = "post">
        <p>
            <textarea name = "query" cols="28" rows="5"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Run MySQL Servlet" />
            <input type = "reset" value = "Clear Command" />
        </p>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <TABLE id="results" align="center">
            <%
                ArrayList<String> columns = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("queryColumns");
                ArrayList<String[]> results = (ArrayList<String[]>)request.getAttribute("queryResults"); 
                out.println("<TR align='left'>");
                if(columns != null && !columns.isEmpty()){
                    for(String columnName: columns ){
                       out.println("<TD>"+columnName+"</TD>");
                    }
                }
                out.println("</TR>");
                //print data
                if(results != null && !results.isEmpty()){
                    for(String[] rowData: results){
                       out.println("<TR align='left'>");
                       for(String data: rowData){
                          out.println("<TD>"+data+"</TD>");
                       }
                       out.println("</TR>");
                    }
                }
            %>
        </TABLE>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably an URL encoding problem..., what is really in your request.getParameter("query") ?

Comment: I was outputting the string stored in "query" and it was outputting my commands perfectly. I can also run complex SELECT commands with no trouble and perfect output. The problem arises when I use * only, but the "query" string returned is still something like SELECT * FROM table; so I know the query string is holding true.

Comment: Just to isolate problem... you probably have tried this query hard coded?

Comment: I have tried the query hard-coded. Just to update, I am having the problem with only specific columns as well. There is a single column in each table that causes the script to fail. I can call each other column just fine, but one column will only return the column name, or nothing at all.

Comment: A small detail I see that doesn't have anything to see with your problem but could help in future : replace query.toString().toLowerCase().contains("select") by query.toString().toLowerCase().startWith("select") so if you have this text in content it will not cause problems

Comment: What's the name of the column that, if included, causes no results to be shown? Regarding the update/delete - are you sure your statement matches any rows? As a separate point, I presume this is test code? (You know that there will be only one instance of your servlet shared between client requests and so one shared database connection won't work in a multi-user environment, right?)

Comment: This is just test code and I am aware of those other issues. One example of a column name that doesn't work is "numworkers". I can call any other column in the jobs table, but not numworkers. I am positive that the INSERT and DELETE commands are valid.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `select *` query have you checked for any exceptions being thrown.
This line `row[i] = (String) resultSet.getObject(i+1);` can cause classCastExceptions if the returned object is not of type string.
Your column *numworkers* seems to be like an integer to me.